# StreamPlot, ListStreamPlot does not visualize vector field properly

Tags: plotting, differential-equations, visualization

I am reopening [my question about empty stream plots](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/96903/streamplot-is-empty).
I couldn't find a choice for parameters that would give me a proper stream
plot for the following example.

```
StreamPlot[{y, -100000 x - y}, {x, -0.1, 0.1}, {y, -100, 100}]
```

Using ListStreamPlot (as suggested) did not work either.
Note that the problem does not occur for

```
StreamPlot[{y, -x - y}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}]
```

How can this scaling issue be addressed in order to obtain a sensible visualization of the vector field?

Comment: You aren't "reopening" your old question. Seems you're posting almost a dup

Comment: just un-accept the accepted answer there if it doesn't solve the problem and edit the question to clarify it