# StreamPlot not working

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I'm new to Mathematica and I'm trying to plot the directional field of the following differential equation:

$$\dfrac{\mathbb{d}W}{\mathbb{d}R} = \dfrac{-0.02W + 0.00002RW}{0.08R-0.001RW}$$

And I was expecting to acheive the following results:
[image]

So I tried to use `StreamPlot` in the following command:

```
StreamPlot[{1, (-0.02 W + 0.00002 R W)/(0.08 R - 0.001 R W)}, {R, 0, 3000}, {W, 0, 150}]
```

But It caused the following errors:

```
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
Power::infy: Infinite expression 1/0. encountered. >>
Infinity::indet: Indeterminate expression 0. ComplexInfinity encountered. >>
```

What am I doing wrong and how do I fix it?

Comment: Notice when R==0 and W==0 your denominator==0. Try {R,1,3000}, {W,1,150} and your 1/0 errors go away. That still leaves other issues, like your {1,(-0.02W+0.00002R W)...} when none of the examples in the help pages for StreamPlot use a 1 the way you do. Maybe you want {(0.08 R - 0.001 R W), (-0.02 W + 0.00002 R W)} but it is difficult to tell.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple tweaks improve the results.

1) @Rahul's `myStreamPlot` from [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42763/why-isnt-my-stream-code-plotting-multiple-solution-curves/42770#42770) will fill in the streams nicely.

2) As @Bill writes, better to separate `dW` and `dR` in the plot command (otherwise the `R` direction will always have positive sign, which contradicts the predator-prey origin of the equations).

Together:

```
Options[myStreamPlot] = Options[StreamPlot];
myStreamPlot[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
  With[{a = OptionValue[AspectRatio]}, 
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)} (f /. {x -> x0 + u (x1 - x0), y -> y0 + v/a (y1 - y0)})
  , {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a}, opts] /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[({x0, y0} + {x1 - x0, (y1 - y0)/a} #) & /@ pts],
  PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]]

myStreamPlot[{(0.08 R - 0.001 R W), (-0.02 W + 0.00002 R W)}, {R, 0, 3000}, {W, 0, 150}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: I don't know, it works for me on 11.0.1.  Try a fresh kernel?

Comment: Thankx, I closed and reopened the program and tried again and it worked. Could you please add some explanation on how the code works, I'm a beginner in Mathematica .

Comment: Despite its name, `myStreamPlot` is not my work.  To understand how it works, see the description by its author @Rahul [here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42770/6358).