# StreamPlot plots only one plot

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

I want a phase diagram that characterizes the path of `p` and `s` using

```
StreamPlot[
 {p^1.3 - .036*s, 0.05*p - 1500000000000/s},
 {s, 10^8, 2*10^8},
 {p, 100000, 200000}, 
 PlotRange -> {{10^8, 2*10^8}, {100000, 200000}}
]
```

[image: The Output]

But that is not right.  I'm expecting more paths.

Any suggestions on how to get more paths?

(I know, I have some big numbers, but if it provides one path, why not others? I'd rather not re-scale if I can get it to work this way because the quantities are meaningful.)

Comment: `StreamPlot` does not do well with poorly scaled domains, in my experience. In rescaling, you can use `Ticks` to get the ticks marked as you like.

Comment: Try @Rahul's `myStreamPlot` from [this answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/42763/why-isnt-my-stream-code-plotting-multiple-solution-curves/42770#42770) to improve the spacing

Answer (score 6):

Like this?

```
StreamPlot[{(p^1.3 - .036*s)/1000, .05*p - 1500000000000/s} /. s -> 1000 s // Evaluate,
 {s, 10^5, 2*10^5}, {p, 100000, 200000},
 PlotRange -> {{10^5, 2*10^5}, {100000, 200000}}, 
 FrameTicks -> {{Automatic, Automatic},
   {Charting`ScaledTicks[{#/1000 &, 1000 # &}], 
    Charting`ScaledFrameTicks[{#/1000 &, 1000 # &}]}}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Comment: My goodness that's beautiful! FYI, that is the phase diagram of the total U.S. housing market where the horizontal axis is the average housing unit price and the other axis is housing supply. A change in the cost of ownership, e.g. will leave the system off the saddle point static equilibrium.

Comment: There's a problem with the solution provided by Michael E2.  The axis seemed to be reversed, or, is it possible that they have been rescaled incorrectly?