# Why Mathematica doesn't let me see the saddle form solutions of $2\times 2$ system?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

This is the system $$\begin{align*}\frac{dA}{dt}&=A\left(2-\frac{A}{5000}-\frac{L}{100}\right)\\\frac{dL}{dt}&=L\left(-\frac{1}{2}+\frac{A}{10000}\right)\end{align*}$$

And this is happens when I use *Mathematica*:
[image: stream plot]

```
 StreamPlot[{2 A (1 - .0001 A) - .01 A L, -.5 L + .0001 A L}, {A, -500,
 12000}, {L, -500, 5000}]
```

Note that I need the range of $A$ and $L$ as written above, because I need to see the equilibrium points in there, which are $x_1=(0,0),x_2=(10000,0),x_3=(5000,100)$

Why don't $x_2$ and $x_3$ have the solutions around them in saddle form?

Comment: People here generally like users to post code as Mathematica code instead of images or TeX, so they can copy-paste it. It makes it convenient for them and more likely you will get someone to help you.  You may find this [this meta Q&A](http://meta.mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/1584) helpful

Comment: @MichaelE2 ok. I edited the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The rescaling process was automated in a function called `myStreamPlot` by Rahul in [this answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42770/6358), which I tweaked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157613/6358).  To make this answer self-contained, I repeat it here.

```
Options[myStreamPlot] = Options[StreamPlot];
myStreamPlot[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{u, v, a = OptionValue[AspectRatio]},
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)} (f /. {x -> x0 + u (x1 - x0), y -> y0 + v/a (y1 - y0)}), {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a}, opts]
  /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[({x0, y0} + {x1 - x0, (y1 - y0)/a} #) & /@ pts], PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]]
```

Then it's easy to get a decent stream plot.

```
myStreamPlot[{2 A (1 - .0001 A) - .01 A L, -.5 L + .0001 A L},
  {A, -1200, 12000}, {L, -20, 200}, AxesOrigin -> {0, 0}, Axes -> True]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

Note that I changed the range of `A` and `L` to focus on the equilibria.

I also added axes at `A=0` and `L=0` since they represent isoclines of the system.  This is the Lotka-Volterra predator-prey model with prey density-dependence.  If you're interested in it as a ecological model, then it's only meaningful in the first quadrant, and solutions that start there remain there.

Comment: Oh I see, thank you. What is the term that represents the density-dependence in the equations?

Comment: The `- .0001 A` term represents logistic density-dependence in the prey `A`.  Check out the third page of [this document](http://www2.hawaii.edu/~taylor/z652/PredatorPreyModels.pdf) for example.

Comment: ok, this might be off-topic but hope you could help me anyway :) (I've seen you pf so :) ) .What does the phase portrait mean in biology terms? Supposing that L represent lady-bugs and A represents aphids.

Comment: The phase portrait gives an overview of how the system changes over time, so you can see the dynamics without having to run a bunch of simulations.

Answer (score 9):

One could rescale the variables in order to need a smaller range:

```
StreamPlot[{
 α  (2 - α - λ), λ (-1/2 + 1/2 α)}, {α, -1, 3}, {λ, -1, 2},
 StreamPoints -> Fine, 
 Epilog -> {Red, PointSize[0.02], Point[{0, 0}], Point[{1, 1}], Point[{2, 0}]}
]
```

[image]

Comment: Hm. Having to scale by hand might be a bit disatisfactory. Is there no way to do that automatically?

Comment: Yes, @Rahul wrote such a function, which I'll cite in an answer below.

Answer (score 6):

Just to illustrate the rescaling (as per @b.gatessucks answer: I have voted for):

```
rh = {2 A (1 - .0001 A) - .01 A L, -.5 L + .0001 A L};
```

Rescaling:

```
rhs = rh /. {A -> 10000 u, L -> 100 v};
sim = Simplify[{#1/10000, #2/100} & @@ rhs];
```

Finding critical points:

```
sol = Quiet@Solve[sim == {0, 0}, {u, v}];
```

Classify using second derivative test (just to color saddle points red):

```
pc = {{u, v}, Det[(Grad[#, {u, v}] & /@ sim)]} /. sol;
func[{p__, s_}] := 
 If[s > 0, {Green, PointSize[0.02], Point[p]}, {Red, PointSize[0.02], 
   Point[p]}]
```

Visualizing (using `FrameTicks` to scale back):

```
StreamPlot[sim, {u, -2, 2}, {v, -2, 2}, 
 FrameTicks -> {Table[{i, 10000  i}, {i, -2, 2, 1}], 
   Table[{i, 100 i}, {i, -2, 2, 0.5}]}, Epilog -> (func /@ pc)]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5):

This is an edit:

```
Grid[Partition[

  Block[{A, L},
   With[{sys = {A (2 - A (2 10^-4) - L 10^-2), L (-0.5 + A 10^-4)}},
    With[{args = {A, L}},
     With[{cpts = args /. Quiet[Solve[Thread[sys == 0], args]]},
      With[{max = Max /@ Transpose[cpts]},
       With[{sclsys = Simplify[(sys /. Thread[args -> args max])/max]},
        With[{sclcpts = args /. Quiet[Solve[Thread[sclsys == 0], args]]},

         With[{sclcpt = #},

            With[{sclrng = Apply[Through[{Min, Max}[{##}]] &, Transpose[{sclcpt}],1]},

             With[{sclbnds = {#1 (1 - 0.5) - 1, #2 (1 + 0.5) + 1} & @@ Transpose[sclrng]},

              StreamPlot[
               sclsys,
               Evaluate[Sequence @@ Transpose[Prepend[sclbnds, args]]],
               FrameLabel -> {
                 {L, None},
                 {A, Row[{"Critical point: ", Style[sclcpt max, Bold, Red]}]}
                 },
               RotateLabel -> False,
               FrameTicks -> (
                 {{#[[-1]], None}, {#[[1]], None}} &@(
                   With[{c = #},
                    Array[{#, # c[[1]]} &, {5}, Evaluate[c[[-1]]]]
                    ] & /@ Transpose[{max, Transpose[sclbnds]}]
                   )
                 ),
               Epilog -> {{Red, PointSize[Large], Point[sclcpt]}},
               ImageSize -> Medium
               ]

              ]
             ]
            ] & /@ sclcpts

         ]
        ]
       ]
      ]
     ]
    ]
   ], 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}]]
```

[image]

Comment: I believe the discrepancy in the equilibrium points is due to how you rewrote the equations.  I think the first term in `rhs` should be `A (2 - A 2 10^-4 - L 10^-2)`.