# Ineffective StreamPlot output

Tags: plotting

My command below does not give a very informative `StreamPlot`.  What am I doing wrong?  Similar problem with `VectorPlot`.  `VectorScale -> Automatic` and `StreamPoints -> Automatic` give unsatisfying results.  What could I do better?

```
StreamPlot[
 {1, 1/5 y (1 - y/3500)},
 {x, -10, 50}, {y, -2000, 5500},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 50}, {-2000, 5500}},
 StreamPoints -> Automatic
]

VectorPlot[
 {1, 1/5 y (1 - y/3500)},
 {x, -10, 50}, {y, -2000, 5500},
 PlotRange -> {{-10, 50}, {-2000, 5500}},
 VectorStyle -> Arrowheads[0],
 VectorScale -> Automatic,
 StreamPoints -> Automatic
]
```

Comment: In order for us to be able to help you better, perhaps you could mention in what way you find the current results uninformative, and how you would like to change them so they can be more useful.

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following:   
1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by **answering questions** in your area of expertise. 
2) Take the [tour] and check the [faqs](http://goo.gl/kQNRaS)!   
3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://tinyurl.com/ch98nrh), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. 
Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, [by clicking the checkmark sign](http://tinyurl.com/4srwe2t)!

Answer (score 2):

This is due to the large disparity in the range on the x- and y-axes.  @Rahul created a function to deal with this problem [here](http://http%20:%20//%20mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42770/6358), which I tweaked [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/157613/6358).  For self-containedness, I'll copy it below.

```
Options[myStreamPlot] = Options[StreamPlot];
myStreamPlot[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{u, v, a = OptionValue[AspectRatio]},
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)}
    (f /. {x -> x0 + u (x1 - x0), y -> y0 + v/a (y1 - y0)}),
    {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a}, opts] /.
    Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[({x0, y0} + {x1 - x0, (y1 - y0)/a} #) & /@ pts],
    PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]
]
```

Applied to your problem:

```
myStreamPlot[{1, 1/5 y (1 - y/3500)}, {x, -10, 50}, {y, -2000, 5500}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]