# Rescaling RegionFunction in StreamPlot

Tags: plotting, functions

I often use [a version](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/157612/phase-plane-building-with-streamplot/157613#157613) of @Rahul's `myStreamPlot` ([original here](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/42770/6358)) to make nice looking `StreamPlots`.  Briefly, it rescales the axes to achieve a more even distribution of streams.

```
Options[myStreamPlot] = Options[StreamPlot];
myStreamPlot[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
Module[{u, v, a = OptionValue[AspectRatio]},
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)} (f /. {x -> x0 + u (x1 - x0), y -> y0 + v/a (y1 - y0)}), {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a}, opts]
  /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[({x0, y0} + {x1 - x0, (y1 - y0)/a} #) & /@ pts], PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]]
```

Unfortunately any `RegionFunction` option doesn't get rescaled.  For example,

```
StreamPlot[{Sin[2 π x], Sin[2 π y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

looks good while

```
myStreamPlot[{Sin[2 π x], Sin[2 π y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

doesn't.

Could someone suggest a way to rescale the `RegionFunction` inside `myStreamPlot` to deal with this issue?  I tried myself but couldn't figure out how to modify it.

Comment: does `RegionFunction -> 
 Function[{x, y, vx, vy, n}, 
  Rescale[x, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}]^2 + Rescale[y, {0, 1}, {-1, 1}]^2 < 1]` give the desired result?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This works for `RegionFunction`s that depend only on the first two arguments:

```
ClearAll[myStreamPlot2]
Options[myStreamPlot2] = Options[StreamPlot];
myStreamPlot2[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{u, v, a = OptionValue[AspectRatio] /. Automatic -> 1, 
    rf = OptionValue[RegionFunction]}, 
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)} 
    (f /. {x->Rescale[u, {0, 1}, {x0, x1}], y->Rescale[v, {0, a}, {y0, y1}]}),
  {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a}, 
  RegionFunction -> (rf[Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {x0, x1}], Rescale[#2, {0, a}, {y0, y1}], ##3]&),
  opts] /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[Transpose[{Rescale[#, {0, 1}, {x0, x1}], 
     Rescale[#2, {0, a}, {y0, y1}]} & @@ Transpose[pts]]], 
  PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]]

Row[myStreamPlot2[{Sin[2 π x], Sin[2 π y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}, AspectRatio -> #, 
    RegionFunction -> (#^2 + #2^2 < 1 &), ImageSize -> #2] & @@@ 
  Transpose[{{1/2, 1, 3/2}, {400, 300, 260}}], Spacer[5]]
```

[image]

Comment: This is perfect, thanks!

Comment: @Chris, my pleasure. Thank you for the accept.

Comment: @kglr  The results of running this code on v14 show that the region of vector field distribution is larger than the blue region. Did I misunderstand?

Answer (score 3):

@kglr, yes that works.
Here is a modified myStreamPlot:

```
myStreamPlot[f_, {x_, x0_, x1_}, {y_, y0_, y1_}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] := 
 Module[{u, v, a = OptionValue[AspectRatio], rf = OptionValue[RegionFunction]},
  Show[StreamPlot[{1/(x1 - x0), a/(y1 - y0)} (f /. {x -> x0 + u (x1 - x0), y -> y0 + v/a (y1 - y0)}), {u, 0, 1}, {v, 0, a},
     RegionFunction -> Function[{xx, yy}, (rf[[2]] /. {x -> Rescale[xx, {0, 1}, {x0, x1}], y -> Rescale[yy, {0, 1}, {y0, y1}]})],
     opts] /. Arrow[pts_] :> Arrow[({x0, y0} + {x1 - x0, (y1 - y0)/a} #) & /@ pts],
   PlotRange -> {{x0, x1}, {y0, y1}}]]

myStreamPlot[{Sin[2 \[Pi] x], Sin[2 \[Pi] y]}, {x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1},
  RegionFunction -> Function[{x, y}, x^2 + y^2 < 1]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks!  This works when the `{x, y}` in `RegionFunction` match the `x` and `y` in `{x, -1, 1}, {y, -1, 1}`, but I get an error when I use different variables.  Also could this be expanded to work with the alternative valid syntax `RegionFunction -> (#1^2 + #2^2 < 1 &)`, which also throws errors?