# The vectorfield for nonauntonomous system?

Tags: plotting, differential-equations

The model is a nonautonomous system
$x'=(2+cos(2 π t))x -0.5 x^2-0.5$
and it can be transformed to the autonomous form by

```
eqns = {
  x'[t] == (2 + y[t]) x[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2 - 0.5,
  y'[t] == z[t],
  z'[t] == -4 π^2 y[t]}
```

The equilibria for the autonomous system are caculated as `(0.268,0,0)` and `(3.732,0,0)`.
I need to analysis the system by a vectorfield to determine the type of equlibria and if limet cycles exist.
Any suggestions would be much appreciated!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I don't think transforming the non-autonomous system into that autonomous system is the right way to go.  Notice that the equilibria you mention both have `{y, z} == {0, 0}`, which contradicts the given periodic forcing.

Instead, I suggest transforming it by adding $dt/dt=1$ (see e.g. Strogatz 2015, p. 8).  Plotting that vector field using myStreamPlot (original by @Rahul) from [here](http://%3Chttps://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/193304/6358%3E):

```
sp = myStreamPlot[{1, (2 + Cos[2 π t]) x - 0.5 x^2 - 0.5},
  {t, 0, 4}, {x, -10, 10}, AspectRatio -> 0.3, ImageSize -> 600,
  FrameLabel -> {"t", "x"}]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

You can already make out a stable limit cycle oscillating around $x \approx 4$, but to highlight it with a trajectory from `NDSolve`:

```
sol = NDSolve[{x'[t] == (2 + Cos[2 π t]) x[t] - 0.5 x[t]^2 - 0.5,
  x[0] == 8}, x, {t, 0, 4}][[1]];
Show[sp, Plot[x[t] /. sol, {t, 0, 4}, PlotStyle -> Pink]]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

*Reference*:

Strogatz SH. 2015. [Nonlinear Dynamics and Chaos: With Applications to Physics, Biology, Chemistry, and Engineering.](http://www.stevenstrogatz.com/books/nonlinear-dynamics-and-chaos-with-applications-to-physics-biology-chemistry-and-engineering)  2nd ed.

Comment: Just to complete this helpful answer: There is a second limit cycle near `x~0.27`

Comment: @UlrichNeumann Thanks, I overlooked that one.  I'd assume it's unstable.

Comment: @Chris K It's a good answer. As pointed out by @UlrichNeumann, the second limit cycle is near `0.27` and it is unstable. But I'm more familiar with the phase diagram with Axes `x` and `x'`, and the stable limit cycle will converge to a closed curve. Is it possible to plot in this way within the vector field?

Comment: @keanhy14 I don't think so.  Usually such plots make sense for second-order systems involving `x''`.  Only thing I can think of is wrapping it around a cylinder as done [here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/64407/phase-portrait-on-a-cylinder) but I don't think that will be particularly insightful.

Comment: Thanks, and I love the answer in the way with some references, that' great!

Comment: You're welcome -- Strogatz's book is a masterwork.